# No keepalive sent from client

Tags: sensu

I had installed sensu server,sensu client,redis,rabbitmq on individual centos machines.I can see logs of Sensu client for memory check,but the same is missing in sensu server and sensu server logs show:

> No keepalive sent from client for 248234 seconds (>=180)\",\"status\":2,\"history\":[\"2\",\"2\",\"2\",\"2\",\"2\",\"2\",\"2\",\"2\",\"2\",\"2\",\"2\",\"2\",\"2\",\"2\",\"2\",\"2\",\"2\",\"2\",\"2\",\"2\",\"2\"],\"total_state_change\":0},\"occurrences\":8246,\"action\":\"create\",\"timestamp\":1447675210}"]}

I am new to it .Request anyone to help me out.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15):

I had same issue. I tried to delete the client manually from uchiwa and then with curl, and restart sensu-client and sensu-server and redis as well. No success.Then I found something interesting in google groups

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sensu-users/5Z2kVFKZjwQ

It seems that if you hosts are not well time and date syncronized sensu complaints in this way.

So at the end I just ran ntpdate command as:

```
 # ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

and then restart sensu-client and problem was solved.

Comment: worked for me, I ran ntpdate on all my machines.. irony is, i owned ntpdate 15 years back on netware :)